# convert utc time and offset to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

i have a datetime(in utc) saved in database and i also know the utc offset in the following format.

```
-03:00:00
```

how to convert this to a `DateTime`

Comment: `12:12:12` does not look like a UTC offset to me, or a `datetime` field either. Can you elaborate on the meaning of each part?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548235/convert-utc-datetime-to-another-time-zone
this will help you

Comment: @Oded it is the utc offset. it's range is -12:00:00 to 13:00:00

Answer (score 17):

This simplest way to apply an "offset" to a [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) that you already have is to create a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) structure which holds your offset value, and then simply "add" the offset to the original `DateTime` value.

For example:

```
DateTime utcDateTime = DateTime.Parse("29 July 2010 14:13:45");
TimeSpan offSet = TimeSpan.Parse("-03:00:00");
DateTime newDateTime = utcDateTime + offSet;
Console.WriteLine(newDateTime);
```

This results in the following output:

`29/07/2010 11:13:45`

which is the original time (29 July 2010 14:13:45) minus 3 hours (the offset - -03:00:00).

Note that this technique is merely performing simple arithmetic with your `DateTime` value and does not take any time zones into account.

Comment: Note that the Parse fails when you have the '+' sign in the string. So use the '-' sign or no sign at all! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: What about daylight saving?

Comment: @AnilPurswani You would only be able to apply daylight savings offset if you know the specific timezone rather than just an "hours offset".  The TimeZoneInfo class has a property (SupportsDaylightSavingTime) to indicate if a specific timezone supports daylight savings.  Different timezones may have the same hours offset but may or may not support daylight savings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are likely running into is that most DB drivers when fetching from the database will create the `DateTime` with `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, which may not convert to UTC properly even when you use `ToUniversalTime`. To get arround this I use an extension method like this:

```
    public static DateTime ToSafeUniversalTime(this DateTime date) {
        if(date != DateTime.MinValue && date != DateTime.MaxValue) {
            switch(date.Kind) {
            case DateTimeKind.Unspecified:
                date = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, date.Hour, date.Minute, date.Second, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                break;
            case DateTimeKind.Local:
                date = date.ToUniversalTime();
                break;
            }
        }
        return date;
    }
```