# How to get UTC time based on a DateTime and a TimeZone Offset?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, utc

I have a datetime object, and I know the UTC offset (double).  How can I get UTC time from these two pieces of information?

All of the examples I've seen require a timezone.  Well, I don't know what timezone is, and it shouldn't really matter.  If i have an offset of -7, it could either be PDT, or it could be MST - it's really irrelevant as either would produce the same UTC.  It seems really stupid that I have to convert the offset that I have to a timezone just so the "ToUniversalTime" can pull the offset back out.

Honestly, I'm about to resort to just using something like this:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2014, 8, 6, 12, 0, 0);
Double timeZone = -7.0;
string utc = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}T{3}:{4}:{5}{6}:{7}", startDate.Year, startDate.Month, startDate.Day, startDate.Hour, startDate.Minute, startDate.Second, (int) Math.Floor(timeZone), (timeZone % 1) * 60);
```

can someone please tell me why this is a bad idea?

(someone will probably close this as a duplicate, but I looked at a dozen other questions and none of them were quite the same - they all used the TimeZoneInfo object).

Comment: Why not `DateTime.AddHours` or `+ TimeSpan `? Side note: there are "30 minutes" timezones, so be careful with your hour rounding.

Comment: because I need to convert it to UTC time and when doing so it uses my local timezone, and not the one I provide.  I suppose I could do some substraction and subtract or add the difference between the local timezone and the desired timezone, and then convert it to UTC... but that still seems unnecessary.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361861/convert-utc-time-and-offset-to-datetime

Comment: This feels like an XY problem. Please give more context about exactly what you're trying to accomplish. Do you *actually* need it as a string, or are you looking for something else?

Comment: I'm creating a Google Calendar event through their API

Comment: Marcel:  that's going the opposite direction.

Comment: Just mind the time light saving issue, especially if you hard code your offset!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `DateTimeOffset`:

```
TimeSpan utcOffset = TimeSpan.FromHours(timeZone);
DateTimeOffset result = new DateTimeOffset(dateTime, utcOffset);
DateTime utc = result.UtcDateTime;
```

or

```
string utc = result.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssK", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It's not clear why you want it as a string in the end though...

(You might also want to consider using my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project, particularly as you're likely to see time zone IDs which are TZDB time zones...)