# Can I show date in local time zone while save date in UTC?

Tags: php, timestamp-with-timezone

I want to show date in local time zone but i have saved date in UTC, there is any to show it in local time zone using php.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548235/convert-utc-datetime-to-another-time-zone

Comment: i want to do this in php. Is it posible in php ?

Comment: I've retagged your question so the php guys will see it. I would advise you spend some time expanding it yourself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792066/convert-utc-dates-to-local-time-in-php have you searched about this ??

Answer (score 0):

PHP's `strtotime` function will interpret timezone codes, like UTC. If you get the date from the database/client without the timezone code, but know it's UTC, then you can append it.

Assuming you get the date with timestamp code (like "Fri Mar 23 2012 22:23:03 GMT-0700 (PDT)", which is what Javascript code `""+(new Date())` gives):

```
$time = strtotime($dateWithTimeZone);
$dateInLocal = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
```

Or if you don't, which is likely from MySQL, then:

```
$time = strtotime($dateInUTC.' UTC');
$dateInLocal = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
```

Alternatively

`date()` and `localtime()` both use the local timezone for the server unless overridden; you can override the timezone used with `date_default_timezone_set()`.

you may find these links useful

[Set Default timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

[date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

[local-time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.localtime.php)